# javascript cant get computed style of class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple javascript which uses `getComputedStyle` of an element in DOM to read its background color. Its converting rgb to hex and outputs in html.

Javascript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("elem-container");
var background = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("background-color");

function rgb2hex(rgb) {
     if (  rgb.search("rgb") == -1 ) {
          return rgb;
     } else {
          rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+))?\)$/);
          function hex(x) {
               return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
          }
          return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]); 
     }
}

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = rgb2hex(background);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="elem-container">Some content</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

CSS:

```
 #elem-container {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 200px;
   padding: 50px;
   background-color:#aaaaaa;
   font-family: Georgia;
 }
```

But when i want to use CLASS instead of ID i use this code i found on MDN

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

So my variable looks like `var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("elem-container");`

I change `#elem-container` to `.elem-container` in CSS and change `id="elem-container"` to `class="elem-container"` in HTML and i dont get any result, just white space?

Here is **working** example with ID
http://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/MKeqMN

Here is **not working** example with CLASS
http://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/qbNJJx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between `document.getElementById` and `document.getElementsByClassName`:

`document.getElementById` returns a single element, whereas `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements.

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("elem-container");
var background = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("background-color"); 
// this will fail, because elem is an array
```

---

You could simply pick the first element of the array and it will work - but has other downsides (e.g. you don't know if there is any element or if there are multiple elements, that you pick the right one).

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("elem-container")[0];
```

Multiple elements with the same `class`-name in the DOM are allowed. `Id`-names should be unique. That is why these selectors return a single element ("should be unique") or an array ("0-n elements are expected").

Comment: Could you tell me more about downsides, are they relevant enough to not use ..byClassName?

Comment: Thank you very much for your great explanation and help!

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, so to make it work you have to use the element position in the array: `elem[0]`.

```
var background = window.getComputedStyle(elem[0],null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!